# Do PID values only increase over time? Or can they also generate lower values

Tags: php, process, pid

I noticed that the PID of the processes my webapp is spawning keeps getting larger over time.

For each process, the PID is stored in a file to reference from the web app. I originally had a file buffer of 8 bytes to read the PID from.. While 8 bytes is probably enough, I'm noticing i may need to increase this buffer size if these numbers go up over a long period of time..

Do PID values ever get lower? Or only after a reboot and it starts over again?

What should my buffer size be if I'm reading a single PID value from a file? Should I just set a very large buffer?

Comment: A good start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier

Comment: thanks @deceze, located my max_pid file, /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max, and it is 32768

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On most operating systems, PID's wrap around to 0 after 65535.  It is not a safe assumption to assume that pid's will only grow larger.

In principle, a pid could be any non-negative `pid_t`, which on [GNU systems](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_566.html) is an `int`, so

> 2<sup>31</sup>-1 = 
>   2147483647

would be the largest such pid even theoretically possible.

Answer (score 1):

All depends on the operating system.  For example my openbsd boxes generate pids randomly. So in that case yes they could be lower or higher..